# Designing MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have three tables,

student, studentclass , class

student have sid as primary key, class have cid as primary key.

studentclass ties student and class together and has two columns, sid,cid (no special keys).

Is it possible to get rid of studentclass table and use student and class tables only, without creating duplicate entries in student or in class tables?

(class can have multiple students and student can attend multiple classes)

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. A class can have multiple students, and a student can attend multiple classes, so you should have a linking table that records that relationship.

Comment: So studentclass table is the best solution?

Comment: Yes. It's the only solution.

Comment: Thanks, studentclass should have primary key or other kind of keys?

Comment: You have a natural PK (student_id,class_id). As a rule ALL tables should have a PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the business logic states that, one student can attend multiple classes then it is good to have a linking table, **StudentClass**.

You can think of this as a **Many to Many relationship** where one student can attend multiple classes and one class can have multiple students.

Answer (score 0):

The studentclass table is required assuming that students attend more than one class.

If they do not you can simply add a classId field into the students table and get rid of the studentclass table.

Comment: Thanks, lets say I'll add teacher table, so its one-to-many and many-to-one relationship, how should I implement this?

Comment: If a class is only taught by one teacher, then you can store that in the class table - but another linking table wouldn't hurt

Comment: should I use foreign key in class table (references to teacher table)? (class is only taught by one teacher)

Answer (score 0):

Without the explicit columns, and having previously written a college registration system many moons ago, here are some of the tables that I had implemented.

Student - obvious, list of students, primary information, etc

ClassCategory - Generic categories... (ENG)English, (MTH)Math, (SCI)Science, etc, not the specific class level, but the categories

ClassCourse - These are the things that would be found in a syllabus.. ENG-101, MTH-210, etc.  This would have the common information describing what the class was about, not who was teaching, credit hours, etc but the material covered, maybe any pre-requisites, basic syllabus for someone to review content.

Semester - List of semesters, such as Winter-2013, Spring-2014, etc.

Facility - List of facility locations that a given class would be taught -- could be buildings, campus, etc

Teacher - list of teachers, there contact information, whatever, regardless of specific classes they might teach.

ClassOffering - Here is where all the courses would be, when offered, etc and would have its own PK ID, but also the ClassCourse, Semester offered, Facility, teacher and specific room and times.  You could have the same "ENG-101" course offered 5 times in a day for day and evening classes by different teachers and time slots.

StudentClasses - This is what you are currently at. This would have which student and which specific class OFFERING they enrolled in.  Additionally, at this record you could have a drop, withdrawn status, etc and what other settings may be specific, such as credits attempted, earned, final grade, date completion, etc...  This table would be the basis of computing GPA for a student.

EACH of these tables would have their own respective "PKID" values and each table SHOULD have their own.

Although this is not an obvious complete database, but it hopefully can lead you to a better consideration of what you may need to consider.